# Macos Terminal find command to search multiple volumes

Tags: macos, terminal, find

I have multiple volumes connected, and I need to search and delete specific folder `SearchData`.

I've been using

```
find /Volumes/Volume01 . -type d -name 'SearchData' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

It works, but I have 10 different volumes that I need to do that search. Is there a way to search in multiple volumes at the same time?

Also, is it possible to search and delete 2 different folders, one `SearchData` and `WaveformCache` in the same command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wildcards for the top directory and the or action (-o) to select two.

Try this:

```
find /Volumes/Vol* . -type d \( -name WaveformCache -o -name SearchData \) -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```